# Recycle function parameters instead of writing out each time

Tags: r

I have a custom function `fit_xgb` which takes several paramaters:

```
fit_xgb(train_df = training_data, 
                          test_df = testing_data, 
                          training_features = c("spender", "spend_7d", "spend_30d", "d7_utility_sum", "recent_utility_ratio", "IOS",
                                                "is_publisher_organic", "is_publisher_facebook"), 
                          hyper_param = hyperparam_value, 
                          binary_target = "spender",
                          regression_target = paste0("spend_", day_m, "d"),
                          spend_from = paste0("spend_", day_n, "d"),
                          spend_to = paste0("spend_", day_m, "d"))
```

I have another custom function `fit_rf` that takes the same paramaters:

```
fit_rf(train_df = training_data, 
                          test_df = testing_data, 
                          training_features = c("spender", "spend_7d", "spend_30d", "d7_utility_sum", "recent_utility_ratio", "IOS",
                                                "is_publisher_organic", "is_publisher_facebook"), 
                          hyper_param = hyperparam_value, 
                          binary_target = "spender",
                          regression_target = paste0("spend_", day_m, "d"),
                          spend_from = paste0("spend_", day_n, "d"),
                          spend_to = paste0("spend_", day_m, "d"))
```

Rather than spell out the params each time I call either of these two functions, I'd like to create a single variable that I can call once:

```
model_function_params <- list(
  train_df = training_data, 
  test_df = testing_data, 
  training_features = c("spender", "spend_7d", "spend_30d", "d7_utility_sum", "recent_utility_ratio", "IOS",
                        "is_publisher_organic", "is_publisher_facebook"), 
  hyper_param = hyperparam_value, 
  binary_target = "spender",
  regression_target = paste0("spend_", day_m, "d"),
  spend_from = paste0("spend_", day_n, "d"),
  spend_to = paste0("spend_", day_m, "d"))

fit_rf(model_function_params)
fit_xgb(model_function_params)
```

This does not work. I know I would have to specify each list component with

```
training_data = model_function_params$train_df
test_df = model_function_params$test_df
etc
```

But that it almost going to defeat the purpose of writing less code and keeping my script minimal.

Is there an elegant way of defining the function parameters once, then passing to either fit_rf or fit_xgb without having to specify the parameters twice in my code?

Comment: check out `do.call`.

Comment: Like this? `do.call(fit_xgb, model_function_params)`

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Alright :)
Should I delete?